# Asp.net client side validation error message keeps displaying on value change from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, validation

I am using asp.net client side validation with input tag.

This input field is required field so It displays when the input has no value. Then when I change the value of input tag by using jquery like the following.

```
$("input").attr("value", "someValue");
```

The validation error message does not go away but when I manually edit the input value by typing some values, then the error message goes away.

Is there a way to trigger(?) client side validation when the "value" attribute of input tag changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try id selector.
Like $("#input").val("someValue");
And call this before the execution submit.

Thanks

Comment: thanks but it does not seem to work the error message does not go away..

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem by adding "focusout()" method.

So like

```
 $("#input").val("someValue").focusout();
```

I think focusout() method trigger client validation again?

Anyway, I wish someone would get help from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger unobtrusive validation only for the element that needs to be verified.

For ex, calling the valid() method after setting the value to the input, clears the validation error message.

$("#input").attr("value", "someValue");
 
$('#input').valid();